# Programmatically accessing a hidden field from SQL Reporting Services

Tags: c#, reporting-services

I have a table which contains a reference to some other table which in order contains a field with binary data of a PDF file.
This table is used in a SSRS (SQL Reporting Services) report. The table which contains the binary field, is not included in the report (to avoid performance issues). The user also should not see any Id fields of the tables in the report.

Here is a simplified structure:

```
Table A
------------
AId (should not be visible in the report)
SomeField


Table B  (not included in the report)
------------
BId 
FK_AId
BinaryPdfData
```

I need to develop a C# application which exports data from the SSRS using Render function and puts exported files in some folder.

I need somehow to get all the AId fields (which are not visible in the rendered report) and collect all the related PDF letters from the database.

**How do I add the AId field to the SSRS report in a way that this field is invisible in the report but accessible from C# code, so I can use the AId field to collect all the related PDF letters?**

Answer (score 0):

You can add your aid field as a queried parameter and access that parameter through your C# code.